# Does SQL Server 2000 MSDE have DTS?

Tags: sql-server

We are currently evaluation our hosting options and the cheapest suitable option we've found only has SQL Server 2000 MSDE as the database server.

Does this version have DTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run DTS packages on SQL Server 2000 MSDE, but you'll need to create them on a full copy of SQL Server and copy them across.  Run them using DTSrun.exe

I've used MSDE on several occasions under similar circumstances.  It's quite sufficient for small to medium sized websites but if you have anything of complexity then a full version of SQL Server is to be recommended. You'll most likely need an additional tool too to set up scheduled jobs [Lazy Coding's SQLScheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx) is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2000 MSDE does have it; however, SQL Server 2005 Express does not have SSIS which is a replacement for DTS.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It supports running them but not developing them. Here's an article from Microsoft that discusses it.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175272(SQL.80).aspx)